# How to make a Windows touch pad acts like a Mac touch pad?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mouse, driver

I am trying to write something for windows using WINAPI, so I can make the touch pad do whatever the mac touch pad do.

I have checked using Spy++ what WM messages the two finger taps and etc. send to the OS, but figured out it sends only those plus/minus:

```
WM_LBUTTONDOWN
WM_LBUTTONUP
WM_MOUSEHOVER
WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
WM_MOUSELEAVE
WM_MOUSEMOVE
WM_RBUTTONDOWN
WM_RBUTTONUP
```

When I tried to see what happend when clicking with 3 or 2 fingers it didn't send any particular message, unless I moved them a bit.

firstly i would like to start with this:

when 5 fingers going down show desktop (as `win+D` does).

- How to write (driver?) something that can diagnose 5 fingers touching simultaneously    the touch pad? 
  Of curse there is no OS messages for this, but I can make some unique combination of existed  messages and by that diganose it.
- If I need to write a driver can I do it generic for most of the touchpad, can I do it as add-on?
- If you can post a good tutorial you are familiar with for writing a driver for windows, pls, cause I have no clue about it.
- Do I need anything else to take into account :

> ```
> 1. Diagnose 5 fingers mouse events.
> 2. Make a thread in Explorer on startup that handle those new mouse messages.
> ```

thanks in advance

[Mouse Input Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Many touchpads don't support more than two touches. Some don't even support more than one. You can get drivers that enable two-finger scrolling, but these are hardware-dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't.

First, there are touchpads that can physically detect only 1 finger touch, and for those who can detect many - their *drivers* do the translation for you.

Windows does not have any inherent support for reading multiple touch inputs - it relies on the touchpad drivers to provide them.

You can achieve your goal for SOME devices by writing your own touchpad driver (probably starting from Linux touchpad drivers and Windows driver development kit), but this is far from being simple.

And, you'll need to do this for *each and every* touchpad device you want to support (from Synaptics, Alps Electric, Cirque to name the few)

Only after that you can move on to implementing the reaction for the touchpad actions in applications like Explorer.

Comment: Minor correction: Windows does have multitouch support. See the `WM_TOUCH` message. However it depends on driver support, which is the missing link here.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I forgot about WM_TOUCH.